# Order-driven vs quote-driven markets

Tags: microeconomics, reference-request, markets, financial-markets, nonexpert

What is the difference between order driven and quote driven markets? Is there any theoretical microstructure book that gives the intuition behind the types of markets with respect to the orders that traders give to the market makers to buy or sell an asset or a security?

Comment: Welcome to Economics:SE. Thank you for your question; please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like many other stacks, [we expect questions to provide evidence of prior research](https://economics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done. Our [help center](https://economics.stackexchange.com/help), and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions.